# Rails routes that make more sense

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a controller that will create user relationships from ajax requests. The controller needs to know who the two users are and what type of relationship (parent-child, spouse, etc).

The current routes I have are:

```
put 'relationships/:id/:second_id/:type'
get 'relationships/:id/:second_id/:type'
patch 'relationships/:id/:second_id/:type'
delete 'relationships/:id/:second_id/:type'
```

for my methods: `create, show, update, delete`.

My question is, Can I make a `do` block to write this more succinct? Also, is this the best way to do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
resources :users do
    resources :family_relationships, :only => [:create, :update, :delete, :show], path: 'relationships', as: :relationships
  end
```

which gives me these routes:

```
      user_relationships POST   /users/:user_id/relationships(.:format)     family_relationships#create
       user_relationship GET    /users/:user_id/relationships/:id(.:format) family_relationships#show
                         PATCH  /users/:user_id/relationships/:id(.:format) family_relationships#update
                         PUT    /users/:user_id/relationships/:id(.:format) family_relationships#update
```

Comment: Which controller/action do these go to?

Comment: the `family_relationships` controller.

Comment: which action on that controller? - sorry missed the edit

Comment: `[:create, :update, :delete, :show]`

Comment: I don't think you can do anything clearer than what you've already got.

Comment: Hmm... okay. Well, I do need to add 'type' some how.

Comment: These `put 'relationships/:id/:second_id/:type'` should already have type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with (though I'm not convinced there isn't a better way):

```
resources :users do
    put 'relationships/:uid/:type', controller: :family_relationships, action: :create
    get 'relationships/:uid/:type', controller: :family_relationships, action: :show
    patch 'relationships/:uid/:type', controller: :family_relationships, action: :update
    delete 'relationships/:uid/:type', controller: :family_relationships, action: :delete
  end
```

Gives routes like this:

```
PUT    /users/:user_id/relationships/:uid/:type(.:format) family_relationships#create
GET    /users/:user_id/relationships/:uid/:type(.:format) family_relationships#show
PATCH  /users/:user_id/relationships/:uid/:type(.:format) family_relationships#update
DELETE /users/:user_id/relationships/:uid/:type(.:format) family_relationships#delete
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do resources in `config/routes.rb`. also it can be nested like -

```
resources :relationships do 
  resources :types
end
```

If you do `rake routes`, it will result in routes available

```
app_root>$ rake routes
```

Comment: That gives me one ID and a type. I need to sneak a second id in there.